# How to remove WP sidebar widget header regardless of theme

Tags: wordpress, widget

I would like to create WP sidebar widget similar to this
[one](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/10/jquery-twitter-ticker/demo.html):

As you can see its fully graphic and I want it to keep style **regardless of WP theme** installed.

*How can I do that within WP ?*

I mean to remove **H tags** or other **unneeded tags** for this particular widget ?

Comment: please click the checkbox if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28

Next: http://divitodesign.com/css/style-wordpress-widgets-with-css/

In order the have the widget's style be theme neutral, you'll need to set or load the css within the widget function, so your specific selectors and graphics would be universally applied.